# Will this program halt

Tags: computer-science

I wonder what is the correct answer from a rigorous computer science perspective.

```
int main()
{
    Generator gen; // True random generator returning 0 or 1 with 50% probability        each
    while (gen() == 0);
}
```

Comment: It will, eventually.

Comment: You can't be sure. Theoretically it could also go with 0 for an infinite amount of time. But in real life problems, yes, it definitely will stop.

Comment: ... But chance of it goes to zero. 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2...

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to model this situation using the Turing Machine model.

Why? Well, Turing Machines don't take chances. There are non-deterministic TMs, but there's no chance involved there; NTMs are no more powerful than deterministic TMs which always have the same behavior in the same configuration. So if we are going to inject chance into the computation it is difficult to inject it into how the TM itself works.

Another possibility is to consider the output of the RNG to be the input tape to the TM. Then the TM's tape is a binary string. Your question can  now we reformulated as follows: is 00...0... a valid infinite binary string for the purposes of input into a Turing machine? We can interpret this two ways:

1. Is 00...0... a valid output of the RNG?
2. Is 00...0... a valid input to a TM?

Modern information-theoretic approaches to randomness answer the first question in the negative. The sequence 00...0... has low entropy and can be finitely described by `while true print 1 loop`. Its sample distribution is not in agreement with the law of large numbers or the central limit theorem. Based on the output, modern approaches would characterize the string as not coming from a random source, a contradiction since we assumed the RNG was a true random source. So 00...0... is not generated by our source.

The standard definition of Turing machines, based as it is in formal languages, does not typically admit an infinite amount of input to be on the tape. That is, the blank symbol is the only one that an appear an infinite number of times. Now, we could interpret the blank symbol to mean 0 and the only input symbol to be 1, which would be allowed, but then we would have blanks in the input, which is not allowed, or a TM not beginning at the beginning of the input. In this case I'd argue the question is similar to the halting-chicken problem: given a chicken as input, does the TM halt? And the answer is similar, too.

In summary: my guess as to the rigorous approach to this problem is either:
- the RNG cannot generate 00...0... and the TM halts for all strings it can generate, so the TM halts; or
- the application of a TM to 00...0... is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

From a "rigorous computer science perspective", your question has a bug: there is no "true random number generator" accessible from a C compiler such as the one implied by the form of your code.

If you assume that your C compiler has access to some hardware implemented perhaps quantum effect thingy that really can call your gen() function, then of course the probability that the code will run N times through the loop without halting is (1/2)**N since you would need to get 1 N times, which implies that for any finite time there is a finite probability that the program has not halted.

The halting problem that is more typically studied in computer science circles is concerned with the behavior of deterministic computer programs (e.g. a Turing machine), which your program cannot be - see for example the wikipedia article on "Halting Problem" for a discussion.